# RegionIntersection for big mesh, AnatomyData["skin","MeshRegion"]

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, mesh

I want to cut a human in half.

Say `skin=Entity["AnatomicalStructure","Skin"]`.

So, `reg=AnatomyData[skin,"MeshRegion"]` is the skin of a human, with about 369000 triangles among 185000 points.

In theory, `RegionIntersection[reg,Cuboid[{-400,-400,-100},{400,400,810}]]` should yield the lower half of skin (the numbers specified by me, knowing the `RegionBounds`).  The resultant mesh doesn't work with `TriangulateMesh`: is there a way to do this with stock MMA?  If no, how best to do it with a FEM package?

Alternatively, we can simply remove those upper-half vertices.  So

```
primitives=AnatomyData[skin,"Graphics3DPrimitives"][[1]];
With[{invalidpts = Join@@Position[primitives[[1,1]],
     {_,_,x_} /; x<800]},
   ReplacePart[primitives, {1,2,1,1} -> 
   DeleteCases[
     skinprimitives[[1,2,1,1]], {___, Alternatives @@ invalidpts, ___}]
]
```

should yield the chopped human, but takes painfully long on my computer (I don't know if it terminates).  Is there a good way to make this code more efficient?

Comment: Can you include the InputForm you obtained for `skin` in your definitions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ClipPlanes` can clip the region by half-spaces `a*x+b*y+d*z+d<=0`.

Since the normal of such hyperplane `a*x+b*y+d*z+d==0` is `{a,b,c}`, so the hyperplane which pass through one point `{x0,y0,z0}` is `{a,b,c}.({x,y,z}-{x0,y0,z0})=0`.It means that we can set `d=-{a,b,c}.{x0,y0,z0}`.

```
human = AnatomyData[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Skin"], 
  "MeshRegion"]
(* bd=RegionBounds[human] *)
centroid=RegionCentroid[human]
normal={1,1,1};
Show[human,ClipPlanes -> {Flatten@{normal, -centroid . normal}}]
```

[image]